# some fields not saved in sql table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby 1.9.3p545 Rails 4.1.4

I am trying to save the fields from this form into a table Profile

```
   <%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
       <% if @profile.errors.any? %>
          <div class="error_messages">
          <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
           <ul>
           <% for message in @profile.errors.full_messages %>
           <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
           </ul>
            </div>
       <% end %>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :password %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :interests %><br />
   <%= autocomplete_field_tag 'interests', '', profile_autocomplete_interest_name_path %>  </p>
   <p>
   <%= f.label :zip %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :zip %>
   </p>
   <p>
   <%= f.label :country %><br />
   <%= f.country_select :country, ["United Kingdom"] %>  </p>
   <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
```

The password and interests fields are not being saved.
The controller is

```
  autocomplete :profile, :interest
  def new
     @profile = Profile.new 
  end
  def create
  @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
  if @profile.save
```

The method in the Profile model is

```
  attr_accessor :password,  :encrypted_password, :password_confirmation
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :password, :confirmation => true 
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, confirmation: true
  validates_email_realness_of :email
  before_save :encrypt_password
  logger.info "post save"
  after_save :clear_password
  def encrypt_password
     if password.present?
         password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
         password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
         logger.info "debug passwords"
         logger.debug password_salt
         logger.debug password
     end
  end
  def clear_password
      self.password = nil
  end
```

The table definition is

```
 def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.string :email
    t.string :interests
    t.string :zip
     t.string :country
     t.string :password
     t.boolean :author
     t.date :dob
     t.string :gender
     t.boolean :optinemail
     t.boolean :optinstories
     t.timestamps
   end
```

From the log

All parameters are passed successfully to profile model, and password built in encrypt_password as a result of

```
   before_save :encrypt_password
```

but SQL statement has the two fields missing and nothing logged after that so after_save :clear_password not actioned

Started POST "/profiles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-29 12:05:40 +0100
Processing by ProfilesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"D8HVrGVeFudwz5O0rvf7orkW/TFJS3kXL6uv9lZOxEU=", "profile"=>{"name"=>"admin", "email"=>"info@good2use.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "zip"=>"b72 1af", "country"=>"United Kingdom"}, "interests"=>"golf", "commit"=>"Create Profile"}

[1m [35m (0.0ms) [0m  begin transaction
   [1m [36mProfile Exists (1.0ms) [0m   [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."name" = 'admin' LIMIT 1 [0m
   [1m [35mProfile Exists (0.0ms) [0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."email" = 'info@good2use.com' LIMIT 1

debug passwords

$2a$10$GJDyoPHEd2/2zhEPRxaMvu

$2a$10$GJDyoPHEd2/2zhEPRxaMvu6v9j5mrOXt5klPgO0WNYvwGGqwrHH3m

[1m [36mSQL (1.0ms) [0m   [1mINSERT INTO "profiles" ("country", "created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at", "zip") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [0m  [["country", "United Kingdom"], ["created_at", "2014-07-29 11:05:53.912000"], ["email", "info@good2use.com"], ["name", "admin"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-29 11:05:53.912000"], ["zip", "b72 1af"]]
   [1m [35m (73.0ms) [0m  commit transaction
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb within layouts/application (277.0ms)

If I try and manipulate any fields in table Profile from the rails console the data appears in the schema but whn saved SQL rolls the transaction back
This is driving the Profile model somehow as teh following log entry is cut

post save

[1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mProfile Exists (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."name" = 'admin1' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mProfile Exists (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction

That would seem to imply routing so here's the only part of routes that mention profile

```
    get "sign_up" => "profiles#new", :as => "sign_up"
    get 'profile/autocomplete_interest_name'
```

Hope soemone can help. It seems to be an SQL matter and it's driving me insane.
Thanks
Eddie Reader

Full model

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :password,  :encrypted_password, :password_confirmation

validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }

validates :password, :confirmation => true

validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create

validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

before_save :encrypt_password

logger.info "post save"

after_create :clear_password

def encrypt_password

```
if password.present?

  password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt

  self.password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)

  logger.info "debug passwords"

  logger.debug password_salt

  logger.debug password

end
```

end

def clear_password

```
 self.password = nil
```

end

def self.authenticate(email, password)

```
user = find_by_email(:email)

password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt

if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)

  user

else

  nil

end
```

end

def self.authenticate_by_email(email, password)

```
user = find_by_email(email)

password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt

logger.info "debug salt variable"

logger.debug password_salt

logger.debug password

logger.debug BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,password_salt)

logger.debug user

logger.debug user.password 

logger.debug user.zip

if user && user.password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,password_salt)

   user

else

   nil

end
```

end

def self.authenticate_by_username(username, password)

```
 user = find_by_username(username)

 password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt

 if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)

    user

 else

    nil

 end
```

end

end

Comment: When you try to do a save in the console and it rolls back, have you tried looking for model errors? `profile.errors.full_messages` or `profile.errors.full_messages.join(', ')`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: In the console, presumably you're either finding or creating a profile instance, then updating some values on it, then attempting a save. You see the rollback in the generated SQL.

Comment: Try something along these lines: `profile = Profile.find(3); profile.interests = "cake"; profile.save; profile.errors.full_messages`

Comment: This is from inside the Rails console: `rails c` from the command line. Obviously you need a profile id for the find that actually exists.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I get an error message saying the email must point at a real email account despite removing all validations. Removed gems valid_email and email_verifier and the record is committed. Re-installing email_verifier it still works. So it So it looks to be a problem in this area. I will do some work to see if it works ok with form submission. So if you want to see how that develops please keep an eye on this record. Thanks a lot for your help so far.

Comment: Why do you need both?

Comment: Through console can't store passwords and neither interests nor passowrds will store through model despite removing both gems and all validations.

Comment: Remember you have to restart your console session after removing gems. Also, after removing the gems do you get any errors on save?

Comment: have you tried changing `password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)` to `self.password =` I know it seems strange but I would give it a shot.

Comment: Good spot @engineersmnky. That code will only assign the password locally to a variable in that method, not to the instance attribute.

Comment: Also, @EddieReader can you put the whole model code up for us to see, I suspect something we can't see is having an effect.

Comment: I get no error messages either through the console or through the application. I can see from cutting records to the log that despite there being no error message when I write to the password field through teh console it is still empty.

Comment: Also your model is clearing the password `after_save` so the instance will have no password by your design. The password should still exist in the DB as `after_save` just executes a block given but you won't see it in the instance and your logger for "post save" will not execute as that's not how it works you can put the methods in any order you choose. They are not executed line by line like a `cli` would be. Also note that if you save this instance again it will clear the password or at least raise an exception for password being `nil`

Comment: Also `after_save` is not the same as `after_create` and trust me this will cause issues in the future on updates.

Comment: Right, I made all the recommended changes and have put up the full model. Thanjs for all your interest.